# Syntax error in UPDATE clause

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to update a value in an MS-Access database.

The query works fine when entered directly into Access, but when I try to update it within C#, I get a "Syntax Error in the UPDATE clause" exception.

```
conMngr.ConnectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_connectionStr].ConnectionString;
conMngr.OpenConnection();
try {

    string query = "select Id, counter from tabAppCounter where userId=" + _userId.ToString() + " and appPath = '" + path + "'";
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conMngr.DbCon);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0) {
        int count = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString())+ 1;
        string query2 = "UPDATE tabAppCounter set counter=@count where Id=@Id";

        conMngr.OleDbcmd = new OleDbCommand(query2, conMngr.DbCon);
        conMngr.OleDbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        conMngr.OleDbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", count.ToString());
        conMngr.OleDbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }        
} catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace);

}
conMngr.CloseConnection();
```

This code fails after the ExecuteNonQuery with a Syntax error in UPDATE clause exception.

I have tried using a prebuilt query string, but that does not work either.

Comment: Is it possible the @count is being treated as a string and not a number?

Comment: I used a prebuilt string before - writing the value into the query directly. Even then, it did not work...

Answer (score 5):

The access driver (and Ole) do not use named parameters, they are positional based. The order you pass your parameters AND the parameters in your update statement do not match and this will give you an error.

You really should be using `?` for the placeholder in the update string.

```
string query2 = "UPDATE tabAppCounter set counter=? where Id=?";

conMngr.OleDbcmd = new OleDbCommand(query2, conMngr.DbCon);
conMngr.OleDbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", count.ToString());
conMngr.OleDbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
conMngr.OleDbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Finally make sure the types are correct, the passed in type must match the type in the database. So if `count` is an int in both places then pass `count` and not `count.ToString()`

Comment: I did these changes. but to no avail :(

Comment: @ty812 - sorry, I was in a meeting. Looks like you figured it out. It has to do with escaping reserved words which you can do with the `[]` brackets (as you pointed out below). Keep in mind though that the above info in my answer still holds true and to make sure your parameters are ordered/added the same as they appear in your sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

In hopes this is going to be helpful to others: This is what worked for me.

Instead of

```
string query2 = "UPDATE tabAppCounter set counter=@count where Id=@Id";
```

I used

```
string query2 = "UPDATE [tabAppCounter] set [counter]=@count where [Id]=@Id";
```

and magically, everything started to work correctly.